# Smallest possible version of abs

Tags: code-golf, math

The abs() function in most languages does one thing: give the positive version of the input. Most of the times this is done using something similar to

```
int
abs (int i)
{
    return i < 0 ? -i : i;
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way to do this with less bytes.
Note that this doesn't have to be more efficient, just smaller

Edit: i forgot to add that you can't use the abs() function in your language

Comment: So basically are you asking to codegolf the abs function, without using it ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. In most languages `abs(i)` is the shortest, and for those languages that require `Math.abs(i)` like Java, .NET, JS, etc. `i<0?-i:i` is the shortest.

Comment: basically, yes. I was just wondering what other languages have to offer when it comes to making this as small as possible

Comment: @DavinMiler Ah wait. You meant this as a challenge without using the builtin `abs`. Not a tips question to see if there is anything shorter than `i<0?-i:i` as alternative?

Comment: What i meant was: create the smallest possible version of `abs`, without using `abs` or `i<0?-i:i`

Comment: @DavinMiler How about `i<0?i*-1:i`? ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen haha, nice one

Comment: @user202729 this one allows certain operators, mine let's you use all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 2 bytes

```
-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X5cLiI25dI24dA25DLgMuYy4jAE)

Just remove the minus sign...

Comment: Works in QuadR too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/1@XC4iNuXSNuHQNuQy4DLmMuIwB "QuadR – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 3 bytes

```
√(AnsAns
```

Square root of input * input. Alternatively, `√(Ans²` is also 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 8 bytes

```r
(x^2)^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfYZusYaijYKRnrKOgC2TomuoZKugomAFZ5pr/NSrijDTj9Ez//wcA)

thanks to @Giuseppe

---

Former, 1 byte longer version :

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 9 bytes

```r
x*sign(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfYZusYaijYKRnrKOgC2TomuoZKugomAFZ5pr/K7SKM9PzNCo0//8HAA)

Comment: `(x^2)^.5` is 8 bytes. Another 9-byter (if we don't care about vectorization) is `max(x,-x)` or if we do care about vectorization, `pmax(x,-x)` for 10 bytes.

Comment: Although of course `abs` in R returns the magnitude of `complex` inputs, so none of these quite works the same as the R version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T T   S T N
_Push_45_-][T   S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_LOOP][T N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBAYiAmEuBk4tTgZOTE8xXADHBImCCixOsjovr/39dQyNjLl1TLgMuUy5DAwMA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Start LOOP:
  Character c = STDIN as character
  if(c == '-')
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Print c
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

---

**Old 48 bytes answer:**

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   T   S N
_If_negative_jump_to_Label_NEG][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_NEG][S S T    T   N
_Push_-1][T S S N
_Multiply][N
S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDEBpFACohBUgqcQCkFkAhQBqju/39dUwA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = STDIN as integer
if(i is negative)
  i = i * -1
  Jump to function PRINT
else
  Jump to function PRINT

function PRINT:
  Print i as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E, 2 bytes

```
nt
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/X9u6/@8kv@H18ce2v0/WtfQQEdB11RHAUgZ6igAGYYGsQA)

**Explanation:**

```
n     # Square
      #  i.e. 5 → 25
      #  i.e. -5 → 25
 t    # Square-root
      #  25 → 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

There are a few interesting approaches to this. All are anonymous tacit prefix functions. H.PWiz added two more.

`⊢××` The argument multiplied by its sign. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXosPTD0//n/aobcKj3r5HfVM9/R91NR9ab/yobSKQFxzkDCRDPDyD/6cp6BpzpSkYALGROQA)

`⊢⌈-` Max of the argument and its negation. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXokc9Hbr/0x61TXjU2/eob6qn/6Ou5kPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/zQFXWOuNAUDIDYyBwA)

`⊢∧×` The LCM of the argument and its sign. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXokcdyw9P/5/2qG3Co96@R31TPf0fdTUfWm/8qG0ikBcc5AwkQzw8g/@nKegac6UpGACxkTkA)

`⊢∨-` The GCD of the argument and its negation. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXokcdK3T/pz1qm/Cot@9R31RP/0ddzYfWGz9qmwjkBQc5A8kQD8/g/2kKusZcaQoGQGxkDgA)

`⊢÷×` The argument divided by its sign. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qi2fYo7YJhv8fdS06vP3w9P9pQN6j3j6gjKf/o67mQ@uNH7VNBPKCg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAVdY640BQMgNjIHEoZehgA) Handles complex numbers but needs `⎕DIV` (**Div**ision method) set to 1.

Comment: Also `⊢∧×` and `⊢∨-`

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 5 bytes

```
s/-//
```

Strip the negative sign

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 13 bytes

```
n->n<0?n*-1:n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7NDoIwEITvPMXGE7Up0YMXfvQJ5MJRPdQCZhEWQguJMTx7bZHLJDv77ew0cpaiKd9WtVJruEqkbwCAZKqxlqqC3I@rASr0SixxzhI40UYaVJADQQaWxJnSw4X24hiTTTwwTM/WARs391hC5z6EhRmRXrcHSPaPr/txDcdMnBLANPPKOVuXAMVHm6qL@slEg7s0LYXId/Hd7DhFrhbbOi32Bw)

Boring, but can't be done shorter without `Math.` or using `-n` directly (a.f.a.i.k.).

Comment: I don't think there is any restriction for `-n`

Comment: @Therandomguy There is, but it's in the comments instead of the challenge..

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

`%*` The argument (implicit) divided by its sign. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSlXrf2pyRr5CmoKuMReUZQBjGJnDWIZZhv8B) Handles complex numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(-x,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco7CoAwEAXAq2wZ4S1oPk3Am9hEJBgwH0KK9fTRqae9465Fz7gf8wn5vAKJz0EUC2SZsXYSSoXYgS3YgDV4w4oNGgYWzreeyqCo/v4B)

**Previous (20 bytes)**

```python
lambda x:(x,-x)[x<0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSqNCR7dCM7rCxiD2f1p@kUKFQmaegq6xjq6Rjq6hjoGOoY6RjrFVQVFmXolCmkaF5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 2 bytes

Multiply input by its sign.

```
*g
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=Kmc=&input=LTg=)

Another square/root solution.

```
²q
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=snE=&input=LTg=)

Slightly less trivial 4 byte solution: convert to string, remove non-digit characters and convert back to integer. Or, if input can be taken as a string, this one can simply be `r-`.

```
sr\D
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=c3JcRA==&input=LTg=)